# How do I check and replace a value if a input contains a certain string using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clear the value of a input field if it contains a certain value.

```
$('#registerajax_email:contains("yahoo.com")').text(function(){
$('#registerajax_email').val('');     
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you asking to *"clear the value of an input field if it contains a certain value"*, or are you really looking to *"clear the value of an input **whenever** it contains a certain value?"*  You asked the first, but just about everyone seems to think you mean the second.

Comment: I will be checking on pageload, not when the user is changing the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that the value of an input field is contained inside the value attribute, not in the element's contents. You need an attribute selector.

Try this:

```
$('#registerajax_email[value*="yahoo.com"]').val('');
```

which uses the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

> This is the most generous of the jQuery attribute selectors that match against a value. It will select an element if the selector's string appears anywhere within the element's attribute value.

The selector you were using (the :contains() selector) does not look at element attributes:

> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof.

However, since you're targeting the element by ID, you really don't need to use an attribute selector at all. Most likely this code should be contained inside an event, as Robert Koritnik suggested, and you can just check the string contains using a simple indexOf:

```
// Register event onBlur (you could also use change, or whatever event suited the situation)
$('#registerajax_email').blur(function() {
    // Does value contain yahoo.com?
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("yahoo.com") != -1)
    {
        // clear the value
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is a lot better than using a regular expression.  It seems simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use an appropriate event handler such as [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) or [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) or [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event)

```
$('#registerajax_email[val*="yahoo.com"]').load(function() {
   $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: This will only register the event if the input element contains the "yahoo.com" string on load.

Comment: Works as specified-- "I will be checking on pageload, not when the user is changing the field."

Comment: I was the downvoter, and at the time it did *not* work as specified, nor the way you intended it to.  I'll remove the downvote now though...

Comment: @js1568: I didn't downvote before but now I'm going to. Sorry, but what is the purpose of using the load function? Doesn't the load function use AJAX to "get" the contents of a url and load it into the jQuery set?

Comment: @Pandincus `.load()` is actually two different functions. I use it in this context: http://api.jquery.com/load-event You are confusing it with this: http://api.jquery.com/load "Note: The event handling suite also has a method named .load(). Which one is fired depends on the set of arguments passed."

Comment: @js1568 - I apologize! You are totally right and I feel like a jerk :-P Please edit your answer so I can undo my downvote.

Comment: @Pandincus Thanks, not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Page load functionality

**or: doing it only once in page lifecycle**

When you want to clear an input box on page load if it contains a certain value. Then check whether your input has a certain value:

```
$(function(){
    $('#registerajax_email[value*="yahoo.com"]').val('');
});
```

or even better, since it's an email

```
$(function(){
    $('#registerajax_email[value$="yahoo.com"]').val('');
});
```

`*` means contains, `$` means ends.

### User filling-in data

**or: checking it every time after user enters something in the input**

This input value is probably related to the user entering an email address. So **the main problem with your code is**: when your call jQuery function, your input doesn't contain the required value. You have to attach to `blur` event to check for the value.

```
$(function(){
    $("#registerajax_email").blur(function(e){
        var context = $(this); // store it because it's used multiple times
        if (/yahoo\.com/i.test(context.val()))
        {
            context.val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Beware of the regular expression being used. because it's easier to check whether your input **contains** the required string.

Comment: Actually, the blur event might be a bit better for this.